# Upgrading Database using dacpac

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, dacpac

I am deploying databases to the client through dacpac. First it checks if they have the database deploy and creates version 1.0.  Future upgrades check to see the clients version. If the new database is version 2.0, it needs to upgrade 1.0 to 2.0 on the clients machine and also update the version number on the clients machine. My code is below.

```
     If checkDB() = False Then
            'Initial Deployment of Database
            _service.Deploy(_package, databaseName, False)
        Else
            'Upgrade
            Dim databaseVersion As Version = GetCurrentDacVersionFromDatabase()
            If _package.Version > databaseVersion Then
                Dim dacOptions As New DacDeployOptions

                _service.Deploy(_package, databaseName, True, dacOptions)
            End If
        End If
```

I Then run a query to verify the version which is.

```
  SELECT TOP 1 type_version FROM msdb.dbo.sysdac_instances_internal WHERE instance_name = 'test4'
```

I verified if the database doesn't exist, it creates it and the version exists v1.0.  But when I do the upgrade to the database, the upgrade works fine with the new changes but it doesn't change the version number to 2.0. When i run the query again, it still says v1.0.  what option or change do I need to make to have the clients database now say 2.0 since it technically made all the changes.

Comment: figured it out anyways by using the option registerDataTierApplication=true

Comment: Please post your answer, and mark the question as answered